# How to display page content in a page template?

Tags: wp-query, pages, page-template

In my WordPress site, I made a custom page template, which contained a custom query [using `WP_Query()`]. With that query, I can perfectly get the posts of a certain category. But I want to show the page contents along with the queried posts.

Thing will be like:
---------------------------

### Page Heading

page contents

#### Queried Post Heading

queried post contents
---------------------------

- What can I do?

Comment: What is the problem? This is a page template, so you have access to the page content. By means of another separate query you gain access to a specific post, for instance, and thus can output its content. So?

Comment: Please be patient before voting down. I's struggling for it and then I found the solution. I tried to Q&A here to share the logic with others - I think it will clarify the fact in a way I's looking for it. Hope the Q & A is clear to you.

Comment: Firstly, I did **not** downvote your question. Secondly, thanks for sharing your knowledge with us. You're absolutely right to do so. I guess, the problem is/was that this _question_ was not that hard to solve for experienced WP users/developers, as well as the fact that you posted the question alone. If you want to question & answer right from the start, just include your answer/solution directly on the same page that you write your question on. Below the _Post Your Question_ button there is a check box **Answer your own question**. Thanks again.

Comment: `wp_reset_postdata()` for the rescue. Should be done _after each custom query_.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I'm using two loops. First loop is to show the page content, and the second loop is to show the queried post contents. I commented into the codes where necessary. I emphasized into the loops, as [Deckster0](http://wordpress.org/support/profile/deckster0) said [in WordPress support](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-display-content-on-a-custom-page?replies=9) that, `the_content()` works only inside a WordPress Loop. I'm placing these code into a my own template:

```
<?php
/*
* Template Name: My Template
*/
get_header(); ?>

<div id="container">
    <div id="content" class="pageContent">

    <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1> <!-- Page Title -->
    <?php
    // TO SHOW THE PAGE CONTENTS
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?> <!--Because the_content() works only inside a WP Loop -->
        <div class="entry-content-page">
            <?php the_content(); ?> <!-- Page Content -->
        </div><!-- .entry-content-page -->

    <?php
    endwhile; //resetting the page loop
    wp_reset_query(); //resetting the page query
    ?>

    <?php
    // TO SHOW THE POST CONTENTS
    ?>                        
        <?php
        $my_query = new WP_Query( 'cat=1' ); // I used a category id 1 as an example
        ?>
        <?php if ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
        <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
        <?php while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>

            <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1> <!-- Queried Post Title -->
            <div class="entry-content">
                <?php the_excerpt(); ?> <!-- Queried Post Excerpts -->
            </div><!-- .entry-content -->

        <?php endwhile; //resetting the post loop ?>

        </div><!-- #post-<?php the_ID(); ?> -->

        <?php
        wp_reset_postdata(); //resetting the post query
        endif;
        ?>

    </div><!-- #content -->         
</div><!-- #container -->
```

Comment: That second query shouldn't be inside `if( have_posts() )` because that statement will always be true. You should call `if( $my_query->have_posts() )` after the `$my_query = new WP_Query( 'cat=1' );` and args lines if you want to check that query has results.

Comment: @t31os you are right. It's my fault. Now corrected the code to such. Thanks for the identification. :)

Answer (score 1):

Two loops is common to do this, but a bit overdosed.

Every post or page gives you the super-variable `$post`. Ever wondered why your `get_post_meta()` works with a simple `$post->ID` ;) ?

So, before you start the WP_Query() that gets your listed posts, you can access the current page-/post-data with `$post->ID`, `$post->post_content`, `$post->guid` and so on.

In the loop, this variable gets filled by the looped post. To save it for later, you can either make a new variable

```
$temp_post = $post

// new WP_Query() + loop here
```

or call

> wp_reset_query()

after the listing. The last function should be called anyway to ensure that the data in your sidebar is the right for the current page/post.